# MongoDB model field is the result of multiplying 2 fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms, mongoose

I'm having a little problem trying to figure out which is the best way to do this:

I have a form where I can set a pricing value to users business in two different ways through a couple of radio buttons:

By members, where I have two fields, "Amount per members" and "Quantity".
By amount, where I have only one field, "Total Amount".

And I have to store this data in the DB in a field named "price". So, if I submitted the form with the "By members" option, "price" would be the result of "Amount per members" * "Quantity". And if I submit the form with the "By amount" option, "price" should be the "Total Amount" field value.

The thing here is that I don't know which is the best way to manage this "conditional" thing on the model, so maybe you can help me :D.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) for your models you can do something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodetest')

// Define schema
var formSchema = new Schema({

  member: { type: Boolean, default: false },      
  qty:    { type: Number, default: 0 },
  amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  price:  { type: Number, default: 0 }

});

// Set up some getters and setters to calculate

formSchema.path('price').get(function(value) {
    if (!this.member) {
      return this.qty * this.amount;
    }
    return value;
});

formSchema.path('qty').set(function(value) {
    if (!this.member) {
        this.price = value * this.amount;
    }
    return value;
});

formSchema.path('amount').set(function(value) {
   if (!this.member) {
       this.price = this.qty * value;
   )
   return value;
});

// Define the model for the Schema
var Form = mongoose.model('Form', formSchema);

// Then use in your code
var form1 = new Form({ qty: 2, amount: 10 });
var form2 = new Form({ qty: 3, amount: 10, member: true, price: 25 });
console.log( form1 );
console.log( form2 );
```

So that will fill in the `price` field in your model with a calculated value where the `member` value if false, but where it is `true` then the value that you pass in will always be honoured.

I'll leave the form handling to you, but this is how you could persist your logic in your model.